# No Voice Recording for Incoming Video on QuickTime On Mac

Tags: iphone, audio, video, quicktime

I have used Quicktime player on Macbook Air to record a Google Hangout video. I have noticed that it doesn't record the voice but only video. I am wondering if there are any settings that I am missing to make sure the audio also works with QuickTime.

If there are no settings, then I am thinking to record the video and audio in my iPhone voice memo together . Then is there a way to add the audio in the video recorder by QuickTime?

My options :

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In this case you can't capture 2 recordings simultaneously with Quicktime. You have use additional Apps e.g Garage Band, [Audacity](http://audacityteam.org), [Audio Hijack](http://rogueamoeba.com/audiohijack/) or a iPhone to record your internal audio.

In previous Quicktime Pro Versions it was possible insert a audio sequence to a Quicktime Movie.

Here’s a quick how-to:

1. Open Apple iMovie
2. Import your Google Hangout Video Screen Capture
3. Add your audio recording to your iMovie project.
4. Export your Video

Comment: Okay, I have Version 10.4 of QuickTime Player. So, you mean even if I record audio from my iPhone (in Voice memo), there is now way with my version of Quick Time to combine the Audio with the google hangout screen capture?

Comment: Yes. You can combine your iPhone Voice Memo Recording as well as your Quicktime Recording using iMovie.

Answer (score 0):

Recording Audio and Video should perfectly work. Did you select your Microphone besides the Recording Button? See attached screenshot

[image: How to record-audio-and-video-with-Quicktime]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I don't think I have done anything like that as I just started the recording by using Start New Screen recording option from QuickTime.I actually did not use microphone/headphones. I just kept my mac on the mac inbuilt speaker and tested whether it was recording or not. Did I do something wrong?

Comment: No I don't think so. Maybe Line-In was selected as audio-in source. What Mac do you use? Mac mini and MacPros don't have a buil-in Microphone. Please go ahead and open Quicktime  > Choose File > New Movie Recording. > To change the recording settings, click the arrow next to the Record button. Then choose your camera or iOS device, microphone, and recording quality. Click the Record button   to start recording.

Comment: I use Mac Book Air 13 inch (Early 2015). I updated my post with the screenshot. The Movie Recording steps you have mentioned is recording me and not the screen, that's why I selected Screen Recording option before.

Comment: Audio wasn't recorded due to "None" Microphone has been selected. You have to select "Built-in Microphone: Internal Microphone"

Comment: So after selecting that, even if I use my head phones to listen the video, it should work?

Comment: I see. You are trying to screencapture Google Hangout video and audio including your microphone. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, with built in voice system of Mac